# Solving for Conditional Variance

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am working on a problem and am a little bit confused.

**The problem:**

P(X=0,Y=0) = .80

P(X=1,Y=0) = .05

P(X=0,Y=1) = .025

P(X=1,Y=1) = .125

Find Var(Y|X=1)

**What I have done so far:** (using)

E(Y$^2$|X=1) - $\big($E(Y|X=1)$\big)$$^2$

**But with this I have been getting:**

E(Y|X=1) = $(0)(.05) + (1)(.125)\over(.05+.125)$ = .71

and

E(Y$^2$|X=1) = $(0)^2(.05) + (1)^2(.125)\over(.05+.125)$ = .71

But with this we get the same answer so that when we do E(X$^2$) - (EX)$^2$

We get:

.71 - .71 = 0

This doesn't seem like it is the right answer to me? It seems like there would be some variation from Y | X = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct; but when you plug into
$$
E(Y^2|X=1) - (E(Y|X=1))^2
$$
you still need to square the rightmost term.

Comment: Ah, that solves the problem. Thank you so much!